# dynamic creation of anchor tags and onServerClick events in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, hyperlink, creation

i have created a dynamic list of employee user_ids by retrieving them from database and all of them are links or are created using anchor tags.i have assigned ids to them and also onServerClick events.but on the click of any link,the corresponding onServerClick function is not getting executed.
so help.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {int id = 0;
            StringBuilder htmltable = new StringBuilder();
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select USER_ID from Employee";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    htmltable.Append("<table style='width:100%'>");
                    htmltable.Append("<tr><td style='text-align:center'><h3>USER ID</h3></td></tr>");
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {

                        htmltable.Append("<tr>");

                        htmltable.Append("<td style='text-align:center'>" + "<a href='' id = '" + (id++) + "' style='text-decoration:none;' runat='server' onServerClick='determine_id_Click'>" + dr["USER_ID"].ToString() + "</a>" + "</td>");


                        // htmltable.Append("<td>" + dr["TEAM"].ToString() + "</td>");

                        htmltable.Append("</tr>");
                    }
                    htmltable.Append("</table>");
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmltable.ToString() });
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
    }

protected void determine_id_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            //string id = (sender as Control).ClientID;
            //Response.Write("<script>alert(id)</script>");
        Response.Write("Hi");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When content is rendered like you are doing, it's rendered on the client.  Hyperlinks like that are processed on the server, and the `onserverclick` is converted to a client-side event call to either `__doPostBack` or `WebForm_PostBackWithOptions`, which causes the server-side postback.  You can generate this yourself by adding `onclick` and calling. [Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference(v=vs.110).aspx).